# Non standard intervals in date histogram in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I'm using Kibana 4 to graph response times. When there is low load on the system, the average responses vary a lot if I aggregate them by second (because there might only be a couple of requests coming in during that  second).

I could aggregate them by minute, but then I would lose a lot of detail. I would like to aggregate by some other interval, like 5 or 10 seconds, but I cannot find a way to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! (maybe in 4.1?)

Now you can select the "Custom" interval.

[image]